# Multiple left joins and combining equals and not equals in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I'm trying to join two DataTables so that the first table is LEFT-joined to the second table twice on the CustID column.  The first plant table must match the PlantID from the animal table and the second plant table in the join must NOT match the PlantID from the animal table.  However when I try this in Linq, it seems to ignore the where clause altogether.

Animals:

```
ID | CustID | PlantID
=====================
1  |   1    | <null>
2  |   2    |    1
3  |   2    | <null>
```

Plants:

```
ID | CustID | Name
==================
 1 |    2   |  b1
 2 |    2   |  b2
```

In SQL the query I want would be:

```
SELECT    a.id, a.custid, p1.id AS PlantID1, p2.id AS PlantID2
FROM      animals a
LEFT JOIN plants p1 on a.custid = p1.custid AND a.plantid = p1.id
LEFT JOIN plants p2 on a.custid = p2.custid AND a.plantid != p2.id
```

Here is my code when trying it with linq to dataset:

```
        DataTable animals = new DataTable();
        animals.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        animals.Columns.Add("custid", typeof(int));
        animals.Columns.Add("plantid", typeof(int));
        animals.Rows.Add(1, 1, DBNull.Value);
        animals.Rows.Add(2, 2, 1);
        animals.Rows.Add(3, 2, DBNull.Value);

        DataTable plants = new DataTable();
        plants.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        plants.Columns.Add("custid", typeof(int));
        plants.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        plants.Rows.Add(1, 2, "b1");
        plants.Rows.Add(2, 2, "b2");

        var test = from al in animals.AsEnumerable()
                   join bl in plants.AsEnumerable()
                   on new { x = al["custid"], y = al["plantid"] } equals new { x = bl["custid"], y = bl["id"] } into gj
                   join bl2 in plants.AsEnumerable()
                   on al["custid"] equals bl2["custid"] into gj2
                   from subbl in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   from subbl2 in gj2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new
                   {
                       aid = al["id"],
                       custid = al["custid"],
                       plantid1 = subbl == null ? DBNull.Value : subbl["id"],
                       plantName = subbl == null ? DBNull.Value : subbl["name"],
                       plantid2 = subbl2 == null ? DBNull.Value : subbl2["id"],
                       plantName2 = subbl2 == null ? DBNull.Value : subbl2["name"]
                   };
        var result = test.Where(st => st.plantid1 != st.plantid2).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

The result I get includes the following row, which I thought would be excluded by the Where clause:

```
aid | custid | plantid1 | plantid2
==================================
 1  |   1    |
 2  |   2    |    1     |   1
 2  |   2    |    1     |   2
 2  |   2    |          |   1
 2  |   2    |          |   2
```

When I try it with linq to objects, the second row isn't present, which I expect.  Here is my code using objects:

```
    class animal
    {
        public int id, custid;
        public int? plantid;
    }
    class plant
    {
        public int id;
        public int custid;
        public string name;
    }
    List<object> testStructs()
    {
        List<animal> animals = new List<animal>()
        {
            new animal() { id = 1, custid = 1, plantid = 0 }, 
            new animal() { id = 2, custid = 2, plantid = 1 }, 
            new animal() { id = 3, custid = 2 } 
        };
        List<plant> plants = new List<plant>() 
        { 
            new plant() { id = 1, custid = 2, name = "col1" }, 
            new plant() { id = 2, custid = 2, name = "col2" } 
        };
        var test = from al in animals.AsEnumerable()
                   join bl in plants.AsEnumerable()
                   on new { x = al.custid, y = al.plantid } equals new { x = bl.custid, y = (int?)bl.id } into gj
                   join bl2 in plants.AsEnumerable()
                   on al.custid equals bl2.custid into gj2
                   from subbl in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   from subbl2 in gj2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new
                   {
                       aid = al.id,
                       custid = al.custid,
                       plantid1 = subbl == null ? null : (int?)subbl.id,
                       plantName = subbl == null ? string.Empty : subbl.name,
                       plantid2 = subbl2 == null ? null : (int?)subbl2.id,
                       plantName2 = subbl2 == null ? string.Empty : subbl2.name
                   };

        return test.Where(st => st.plantid1 != st.plantid2 || st.plantid1 == null || st.plantid2 == null).Cast<object>().ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what I was doing wrong.  My where clause is comparing fields of an anonymous type, which are compared by reference.  The where clause should be

```
Where(st => !st.plantid1.Equals(st.plantid2))
```

to compare the values of those fields.